# How to emulate iOS user agent on Chrome, to enable Apple Pay to show?

Tags: ios, google-chrome, user-agent, applepay

For development-only reasons, how can one make Chrome running on non-Apple desktops trick "Apple Pay" buttons into showing themselves on enabled sites?

The "Apple Pay" button doesn't have to be functional, just get displayed.

Answer (score 2):

As a slight update to @anibe's answer, it is also required to add a callback method to return the supported version, as such:

```
<script>
    window.ApplePaySession = { 
        canMakePayments: function() { return true; }, 
        supportsVersion: function() { return 8; },
        canMakePaymentsWithActiveCard: function() { 
            return jQuery.Deferred().resolve(true).promise(); 
        } 
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This 'trick' worked for my team to enable simulate Apple Pay support. However, note that the styling for the Apple Pay buttons are only available to iOS devices using [custom CSS rules](https://developer.apple.com/reference/applepayjs/applepaysession#2674255)

```
window.ApplePaySession = { canMakePayments: function() { return true; }, 
canMakePaymentsWithActiveCard: function() { return 
$.Deferred().resolve(true).promise(); } };
```

**Assumptions:**

- The snippet runs early before the rest of your Apple Pay session validation code
- You are using jquery deferred to resolve the promise to true